# WPF - LayoutStates VisualStateGroup (non silverlight)

Tags: .net, wpf

I have been trying to the LayoutStates state working in WPF when I realised that its a Silverlight only feature (gurrr).

Just wondering if anyone knows of an alternative to achieve the same result? If not can the same result be easily achieved manually? Specifically I'm trying to slide in new items when I add them to the list...

Any ideas, cheers
Anthony